# Allow inter-device communication on WiFi hotspot?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, android-11

Is it possible to allow devices connected to a hotspot to communicate with each other?

I have a [Ulefone Power Armor 13](https://www.gsmarena.com/ulefone_power_armor_13-11066.php) rolling Android 11 and WiFi hotspot. Multiple devices can connect to the hotspot simultaneously, but it seems the phone is blocking these devices from communicating with each other. Everyone can communicate with the phone itself but not with other devices connected to the same hotspot. Pinging another device from Windows yields

```
>ping 192.168.90.77
Pinging 192.168.90.77 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.90.241: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.90.241: Destination host unreachable.
```

This was not the case on my old [Cat S60](https://www.gsmarena.com/cat_s60-7928.php) phone rolling Android 6. There, all devices connected to the hotspot could communicate with each other directly (I am guessing that Android 11 is to blame, not the phone, but I don't actually know).

Comment: If it's due to AP Client Isolation, you need a rooted device to change `ap_isolate` in [`hostapd.conf`](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf). And that too may not be straightforward because Android usually creates configuration file dynamically.

Comment: This has just started happening to me on a Sony Xperia XZ1. What's really weird is it has not had updates for years. I have been able to connect both a laptop and a raspberry to it and access the rpi from the laptop on many occasions in the past, and now it just doesnt work. Only difference I can think of is it no longer has a SIM card in as I have a new phone.

Comment: @Mangodan2003 check the "security patch level", was probably a new security patch, silently installed, that broke it

Comment: @IrfanLatif at least on my Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra updated to Android 13 and rooted, there are no results for ```sudo find / -iname "*hostapd.conf*"``` - hostapd.conf does not seem to exist

Comment: @hanshenrik already stated: *"And that too may not be straightforward because Android usually creates configuration file dynamically."*

Comment: @Mangodan2003 with Irfran's pointer, I found a solution :D see my answer below (requires a rooted phone tho)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to do this on a non-rooted phone, but for rooted phones: Install [Termux](https://termux.dev/en/) and run

```
pkg install tsu php
```

then run

```
sudo php -r '$confFiles=glob("/data/vendor/wifi/hostapd/hostapd*.conf"); foreach($confFiles as$confFile){var_dump($confFile);$conf=file_get_contents($confFile);$conf2=preg_replace('\''/\\#?ap_isolate\\=?\\d?/'\'','\''ap_isolate=0'\'',$conf); if($conf2 !==$conf){} else{$conf2=rtrim($conf)."\nap_isolate=0\n";}file_put_contents($confFile,$conf2,LOCK_EX);}'
```

and reboot.

Alternatively add this code to a `foo.php`

```
<?php

$confFiles = glob("/data/vendor/wifi/hostapd/hostapd*.conf");
foreach($confFiles as $confFile){
    var_dump($confFile);
    $conf = file_get_contents($confFile);
    $conf2 = preg_replace('/\\#?ap_isolate\\=?\\d?/', 'ap_isolate=0', $conf);
    if($conf2 !== $conf){
        //
    } else{
        $conf2 = rtrim($conf) . "\nap_isolate=0\n";
    }
    file_put_contents($confFile, $conf2, LOCK_EX);
}
```

and run

```
sudo php foo.php
```

and reboot.

Thanks to @Irfan Latif for pointing me in the right direction